# Line numbering in result grid in MySQL Workbench

Tags: mysql-workbench

Is there any way to add some line numbers in the result grid in MySQL Workbench?

E.g. (red numbers):

[image]

I don't want to have to change the SQL query, which I know I can do using [tricks](https://www.quora.com/SQL/How-can-I-add-the-row-number-in-the-result-tuples-of-my-SQL-query/answer/Franck-Dernoncourt?share=1) like

```
SELECT @n := @n + 1 `Number of Submissions`,  t.*
FROM (SELECT @n:=0) initvars, 
    ( SELECT COUNT(*) AS count 
          FROM moocdb.submissions 
          GROUP BY user_id 
          ORDER BY count DESC
    ) t
```

I also don't want to have to export the results.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Not sure if that is a good question for SO, but anyway: no this is not possible. Nobody asked for that so far, so, file a feature request at http://bugs.mysql.com to have that in.

Comment: Thanks, done http://bugs.mysql.com/bug.php?id=73377 . I read it is on topic on SO to ask questions about "software tools commonly used by programmers" http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic

Comment: Well, it's on a sharp line IMO, that's why I wrote "I'm not sure". But there's no close vote, so it's probably fine.

Comment: Surprisingly this feature does not exist neither in [mySql Workbench](http://www.mysql.com/products/workbench/) nor in the proprietary [SqlYog](https://www.webyog.com/).

Comment: The feature exists now (2017, May) in MySQL Workbench 6.3.7, but... the same build for Linux shows row numbers and doesn't show it in Windows version. I can't find any setting in preferences or any option in config files.

Comment: Still missing in Windows as of 6.3.9

Comment: version 8 on windows and still does not show row numbers. #HostilityAgainstWindows lol

Comment: I think that feature was missing in 8.0.15 (according to https://bugs.mysql.com/bug.php?id=73377), but now it is available. I can see line numbers in the result grid in MySQL Workbench version 8.0.18 under Linux. Could you confirm if it is available under Windows as well?

Comment: @matandked still same in windows, workbench version is 8.0.31

Answer (score 3):

MySQL does not provide row_number like Microsoft SQL Server, Oracle, or PostgreSQL. Fortunately, MySQL provides session variables that you can use to emulate the row_number function.

SET @row_number = 0;

SELECT (@row_number:=@row_number + 1) AS num, col_1
FROM
    Table